# Method using LINQ in my Repository that gets null errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a Method in my LINQ 
Basicly what my LINQ query does is that it retrieves data from my database.

A user can choose between two dates and retrieve the data between those two dates. But if a user choose on a date range which there is no data in I recieve this error:

> The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type

It should be okey for the users to search between the two dates even if there is no data,  it should give a error message that there is no data between those dates instead of this error I recieve in my Visual studio.
I am using MVC entity framework model first.

Here is the method:

```
public List<CoreValueAndAverageGrade> GetAverageGradeForAllCoreValues(
    OfficeStatisticQueryViewModel model)
{
    var StartDate = DateTime.Parse(model.StartDate);
    var EndDate = DateTime.Parse(model.EndDate);

    return db.CoreValue
        .Where(v => v.CoreValueQuestion
            .Any(q => !q.SubjectType.Ignored_Statistic))
        .Select(coreValue => new CoreValueAndAverageGrade
        {
            CoreValue = coreValue,
            AverageGrade = coreValue.CoreValueQuestion
                .Where(q => !q.SubjectType.Ignored_Statistic)
                .Average(q => q.SelectedQuestions
                    .Where(s => 
                        s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer != null
                        && s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.HasValue
                        && s.GoalCard.Completed_Date >= StartDate
                        && s.GoalCard.Completed_Date <= EndDate
                        )
                    .Average(s => s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.Value))
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Update: Grade is `Double` and Nullable

Any kind of help is very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception message does say what's happing, but you'll have to investigate further, since you are the only one having information about your model. We have no idea which fields are `double` or `Nullable<double>`, but obviously there is the problem.

Comment: @Steven I Updated with that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the last part of the query - if there are no rows returned after filtering with the `where` clause, then `s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.Value` will definitely throw because you're trying to access properties of an object that is null.

I suppose that if you change the code to this you would get 0 as the final value - then you'd need to check for this value explicitly in your code.

```
.Average(s => s != null ? s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.Value : 0)
```

Otherwise, breaking the query down would be a good idea - it helps both debugging and readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would split up the queries and investigate further. My guess would be that there is some inconsistent data. Probably it happens somewhere where you compare a `double` with a `double?` and the `double?` value is null. Maybe check your records for nulls, which should actually be there.

Comment: IN my LINQ I say that grade must have value. But in some way if there is no value I want to throw out a error message like " there is no data between those 2 dates " instead of recieving error in my method.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually comes up when you are trying to apply an aggregate operator to a result set with no records.  Look at where you are using .Average and I am sure you have a query that returns no records right before.

Comment: is it not possible that if it doesnt return anything, do something that do not give the method error? Beaucse if it doesnt return anything I want to display a message for the user

Comment: Is there any grade between those dates, then there is  no goalcardanswer object between those dates

Comment: Split up your query and step through and debug it and I guarantee that you have 0 records in the result in one of those queries that you are trying to take an average of.

Comment: There is no records on Grade. Beacuse there is no Grade between those dates thats why I receive the error.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.  :)  Then I would remove this line from the query ".Average(s => s.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.Value)" and move the query value to be set to a variable instead of being returned.  Then check that variable for null AND Count() == 0 because the variable won't be null if there are no records.  Then if there are records, apply the last .Average operation. If not, return whatever message you want.